# How many ways are there to place eight identical black pieces and eight identical white pieces on an 8 × 8 chessboard?

Tags: combinatorics

I have the following attempt:
We can choose $8$ white squares from $64$. And then $8$ black squares from $56$. This gives us:
$${64 \choose 8}*{56 \choose 8}$$

Comment: Are two arrangements considered equivalent if they can be obtained from each other by rotation? by rotation and reflection?

Comment: That is not given. But I assumed they are not. If they are then the above one should be divided by 4, right?

Comment: Under the assumption you made, your answer is correct.  If rotations are taken into account, dividing your answer by $4$ would be correct.

Comment: Thank you for helping me out!

Comment: @N.F.Taussig your comment looks like an answer to me